# Can Hive realize batch select?

Tags: hive, bigdata, nosql

I have a list of ids, and a hive table. I want to select all the records with ids in the id list. Currently, I select the records by iterating the id list. However, it is very slow. I'm wondering whether Hive supports batch processing, which can select records with a batch of ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a query and use `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where id in (id1, id2, . . .);
```

Or, load the ids into a table and use a join:

```
select t.*
from t join
     ids
     on t.id = ids.id;
```